# randomly sample to create new dataframe where each there is equal probability dependent on a column python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that has a different number of types and I want to create a subset where each type has an equal probability of being selected. For example say I have something like this

[image]

Now say I want to create a new dataframe of length 10 such that each type has an equal probability of being selected. How would I do this in Python? I was trying to follow this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44979788/randomly-selecting-from-pandas-groups-with-equal-probability-unexpected-behav) but didn't get far.

Comment: Groupby has a sample function: [Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sample.html)

Comment: @noah That works thanks!

Comment: When you figure out how to apply the docs for your example consider posting as an answer to your question for other users in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sample.html). We can simply do this

```
new_df = df.groupby("type").sample(n='enter number of samples', random_state=1)
```